# iOS simulator version

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios-simulator

I tried [Appium iOS tutorial](http://appium.io/slate/en/tutorial/ios.html?java#) and ran the example successfully. I noticed the UICatalog6.1.app runs on iOS simulator with title "iPhone 6/iOS 8.2" on the top of the simulator.

However the title is "iPhone 6/iOS 9.0" when I run the app developed by myself from Xcode. I am wondering which part controls to use different version of iOS simulator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you install Xcode, you automatically get the most recent version of the simulators. However, if you would like to define additional simulators with older iOS versions, you can.

In Xcode, go to Window (on the tool bar), and select Devices. There, you can see a list of all of your current devices and all of your currently setup simulators. If you click the plus on the lower left corner of the screen, you'll get to this screen:

[image]

Here, you can select the device you'd like to use for the simulator and its iOS version. By default, you'll only have the most recent version of iOS, but if you'd like to add older versions, just select 'Download more simulators' and you'll be given the option to download older versions and use them for testing.

Once you've set up the new simulator, you'll be able to select it from the list of available devices to run your app on. Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks! Following your instruction, I can set my own app to use different version of the simulator.

Comment: Does this imply that UICatalog6.1.app sets simulator 8.2? I had Xcode 6.2 when I ran the example first time (did not check which simulator version was used) and upgraded to Xcode 7 recently. However, I have not downloaded version 8.2 since then. And under SDKs folder (Right click Xcode.app.Select 'Show Package Contents'.Contents > Developer > Platforms > iPhoneSimulator.platform > Developer > SDKs), there are iPhoneSimulator.sdk and shortcut iPhoneSimulator9.0.sdk only. Where are other SDKs, such as 8.2, located?

Comment: You can choose the version of the simulator your app is running on. You can run their app on the 9.0 simulator as well, and if your app's deployment target is smaller than 9.0, you'll probably be able to select the older simulator for your app as well.

Comment: Hi Rony, how to run their app on the 9.0 simulator? I have the app.zip.

Comment: Rony, I build my own app for iOS Simulator iPhone 6/iOS 9.0, and use the zipped app to replace UICatalog6.1.app.zip for the same test. However, the simulator, which starts to run the test automatically, is still the one with title "iPhone 6/iOS 8.2". How can I run the test by iPhone 6/iOS 9.0?

Comment: Why mess with the app files themselves? Do you have the source code for the sample app? Try running it directly from XCode and select the desired simulator version on the top left corner (where you also select the scheme).

Comment: I have source files for Hello.app. Hello.app can be run directly from XCode and selected the desired simulator version iOS 9.0. Following your instructions, I can select other desired simulator version too. No problem at all. However, when I use the Hello.app to replace UICatalog6.1.app in the Appium test example (http://appium.io/slate/en/tutorial/ios.html?java#), the Simulator triggered by the Appium is always iOS 8.2. I am wondering how I can set other version for this case.

Comment: Continue. -- I notice this statement in the example java file capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "7.0"). However I have to remove it in order to run the test, and I cannot set it to 9.0 either. It is OK to set it to "8.2". Why do I have to use 8.2? Which part controls it?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with Appium so can't really help you there... :-/